# Why does ng-src not trigger certain property changes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a sample directive that watches for changes in the element, such as offsetWidth.

If I apply the directive to an img element that loads the url via the src attribute, everything works fine.

If I apply the directive to an img element that loads the url via the ng-src attribute, offsetWidth does not get updated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc2" data-semver="1.2.0-rc2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>OffsetWidth: {{offsetwidth}} OffsetLeft: {{offsetleft}}</h1>
    <img testing ng-src="{{'http://scienceblogs.com/scientificactivist/wp-content/blogs.dir/392/files/2012/04/i-dcb85296b3695e8ce6d1ae4d660cea30-Smiley-face.gif'}}"></img>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('test', []).
  directive('testing', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(
        'element.offsetWidth',
        function(newVal, oldVal) {
          scope.offsetwidth = element[0].offsetWidth
        }
      )
      scope.$watch(
        'element.offsetLeft',
        function(newVal, oldVal) {
          scope.offsetleft = element[0].offsetLeft
        }
      )
    }
  });
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XTusNSFedqeeDMvBaHC6?p=info)

**UPDATE:**

I applied Buu Nguyen's solution below to ensure that the right changes were being watched, however there appears to be a timing issue.  When reloading the page multiple times, I am noticing that sometimes the value gets updated correctly and sometimes it does not.

Updated javascript:

```
angular.module('test', []).
  directive('testing', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return element[0].offsetWidth
        },
        function(newVal, oldVal) {
          scope.offsetwidth = element[0].offsetWidth
        }
      )
      scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return element[0].offsetLeft
        },
        function(newVal, oldVal) {
          scope.offsetleft = element[0].offsetLeft
        }
      )
    }
  });
```

[Updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qGLDZSM0w8Fpz7Rw8G7E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't watch properties of `element` because it's not in the scope.  One way to fix this without polluting the scope with unnecessary field is passing in the watch function to `$watch`.  [Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NqLDvqKoomOqiXoDzenb?p=preview).

```
angular.module('test', []).
  directive('testing', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on('load', function() { 
        scope.offsetwidth = element[0].offsetWidth
        scope.offsetleft = element[0].offsetLeft
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  });
```

Note: `img`'s `load` event might not work reliably across all browsers. For a more robust approach, try this [library](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).

Comment: Interesting.  Then how was it working before?  Calling 'element.offsetLeft' to watch is returning the right value so it seems to be evaluating correctly on the scope.

Comment: If something is not in scope, scope can't watch it via string expression. However, watch listener is always initialized once with the initial value (read the doc or code, if you want to know why), so some lucky timing might get your original code works for certain property at certain point of time, but that doesn't meant it's correct code.

Comment: It's easy to verify, instead of using `element[0].offsetLeft` inside the listener, use `newVal`. I'm sure it will be `undefined`.

Comment: I just noticed this solution is not guaranteed to work.  There is a timing issue.  I reloaded the page 10 times and one of those times, 0 got returned for the offsetWidth.

Comment: Good catch. If the img is loaded after the initial digest loop, when its size is changed, the watch isn't processed.  I updated the code to handle 'load' event and run the loop.

Comment: I'm confused why digest might not be called.  I thought that by loading the image through ng-src, I'm applying an angular directive, which means any changes will automatically be detected and digested?

Comment: `ng-src` doesn't handle image-finish-loading event to perform digest. The first time a digest is run, the image might still have offsetWidth being 0. When it is loaded, we must explicitly trigger digest. This applies for everything that is changed outside AngularJS's control. Leaky abstraction you might say...

Answer (score 0):

Following up Buu Nguyen's answer, which is correct, I should say that it's not advised to use a watcher to monitor the DOM, as [the Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) state under the "Scope $watch Performance Considerations" section:

> Dirty checking the scope for property changes is a common operation in
>   Angular and for this reason the dirty checking function must be
>   efficient. Care should be taken that the dirty checking function does
>   not do any DOM access, as DOM access is orders of magnitude slower
>   then property access on JavaScript object.

I'm not sure if that will be a problem in your case, but keep it in mind.

Comment: Can I monitor the DOM in another way then?  If my intention is for the directive to do something based on the current size and position of the element as it was rendered on the page, what would you suggest?

Comment: I haven't done anything like this before in Angular, so I don't have a straight answer. What renders the element? Would it be possible for your directive to do that so it knows the element's size and position without needing to monitor those properties?

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing, but it could be that you directive runs after ng-src and so it does not pick up the change because it misses it in time(considering the image is in browser cache). The default priority for directive is 0, but ng-src has 99 so it would not hurt to try and assign your testing directive a priority higher than 99.